# Use filter.js streaming with Wordpress JSON API

Tags: jquery, wordpress, performance, filtering, json-api

I have [filter.js](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/tree/master#add-data-using-ajax-streaming) working well with the [Wordpress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) but I have had to tell the JSON API to output all the posts but specifying `&count=-1` (usually they are paged in 10s).

This is fine while there aren't a huge number of posts but as more are added, the longer the [Wordpress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) will take to generate the JSON.

[filter.js](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/tree/master#add-data-using-ajax-streaming) offers streaming whereby it grabs chunks of a JSON file and incrementally adds them to the page.

### The real issue:

How can I get the 'streaming' (which has an AJAX request format of `.json?offset=0&limit=50`)  to use the Wordpress JSON API paged results? Each new page requires a new [Wordpress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) call `&page=2` etc.

Below is the relevant code I have so far but you can find all of it in a paste bin here: http://pastebin.com/EKhBddmh

```
apiLocation: '/api/get_posts/?post_type=business&count=-1',

settings: {
  filter_on_init: true,
  filter_criteria: {
    location: ['.js__filter-location .TYPE.any', 'taxonomy_business_location.ARRAY.slug'],
    type: ['.js__filter-type .TYPE.any', 'taxonomy_business_type.ARRAY.slug']
  },
  search: {
    input: '#filterSearch',
    search_in: '.media__title, .media__body, .media__footer'
  },
  filter_types: {
    any: function( current_value, option ){
      if ( current_value === '') { return true; }
      else { return current_value === option; }
    }
  },

  streaming: {
    data_url: filter.apiLocation,
    stream_after: 1,
    batch_size: 10
  },
}

init: function(){
  return FilterJS( filter.get_api_data( filter.apiLocation ).posts, '#resultsList', filter.view, filter.settings );
}


get_api_data: function( api_location ){

  var data;

  $.ajax({
    async: false, //thats the trick
    url: api_location,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ){
       data = response;
    }
  });

  return data;

},
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work...

Try adding these configuration changes. Filter.js will add the `params` options as query parameters to the request:

```
filter = {

    filterCount: 0,
    apiLocation: '/api/get_posts',

    settings: {

        ... keep current settings, including streaming parameter ...

        params: {
            'post_type': 'business',
            'page': 1,
            'count': 10
        },
        callbacks: {
            after_filter: function( result ){

                ... keep current function ...

            },
            before_add: function() {
                filter.settings.params.page++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the `get_api_data` function (just let filter.js handle the ajax requests) and change `init` to:

```
init: function(){

    if ( $('body').hasClass('view-map') ) {
        window.googleMap.init();
    }

    filter.bind();
    filter.create_results();

    return FilterJS([], '#resultsList', filter.view, filter.settings);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. As far as I can tell though, `params` is never being used. Nothing is loaded and no console errors.

Comment: The documentation mentions nothing about a `params` object.

Comment: That is correct, but the `fetchData` function of filter.js uses `params = this.options.params || {}`. Which is used in the ajax call: `$.getJSON(opts.data_url, params)`. Because `this.options` equals `filter.settings`, the `params` option should be passed onto the ajax call. Are you using the latest filter.js?

Comment: I'm using 1.5.2 which is the latest. Here is the code I have implemented based on your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/ibZ3UT8X

Comment: Which requests are send to the server? (check with your browser's console). You should also add the count parameter, see answer.

Comment: There also seems to be a problem with the initialization of `filter`, because `data_url: filter.apiLocation` is undefined. When I add a hardcoded url, filter.js begins to send ajax requests.

Comment: Ok, I can see that the correct request is being made and is returning with a status of 200 and 10 results. The post object is no longer being passed to the view though. Where `[]` now is in `return FilterJS([], '#resultsList', filter.view, filter.settings);`

Comment: You could add the `data` parameter to the `before_add` callback and set a breakpoint in it, to check the data. Filter.js should call the `view` function for each record in this data for each retrieved page. Could you make a (stripped down) fiddle?

Comment: This is a stripped down version. Not sure how to simulate paged JSON http://jsfiddle.net/d2a78wwy/

Comment: The data isn't passed to the `before_add` method. It is passed directly to the view which is now replaced with `[]` :(